# Group by (x, y) in rleid

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I have this data.frame:

```
    x      y      Month   TMax
    660.5 4905.5     8 29.70394
    661.5 4905.5     8 30.16751
    662.5 4905.5     8 31.16097
    663.5 4905.5     8 32.15874
    664.5 4905.5     8 32.89709
    ---                            
    705.5 4954.5     8 37.00475
    706.5 4954.5     8 36.98650
    707.5 4954.5     8 36.87743
    708.5 4954.5     8 36.82732
    709.5 4954.5     8 36.77084
```

in this data.frame there are 2500 rows.

I need to count the number of consecutive days (Consec_Days) in one month with Tmax>33C, by (x,y).

I've tried with

```
  DataMax[, Consec_Days := seq_len(.N), rleid(TMax > 33)]
  DataMax[TMax < 33, Consec_Days := NA]
  DataMax
```

But I have too many counts. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hello,
Do you have an example of the ouput you are expecting?
Do you want a data.table with one row per location(x,y) and per month?
Or do you want a data.table with the same number of rows as you data.frame?

Comment: You say *"by (x,y)"* but don't include them in your grouping. Have you tried that? I don't know how robust that will be as-is, though, as grouping by exact values of floating-point columns may run into problems (based on IEEE-754 and [R-FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)). The additional grouping may *appear* to work fine, but the problem with floating-point equality en masse is that it may be unequal *silently*. There are likely ways to deal with this (use fixed-precision strings).